# Failed to delete a project from integration service catalog(SSISDB)

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I am trying to delete a project that is inside the integration service catalog (SSISDB).

To delete it I just connect by SQL managment and right click on the project -> delete

This is the error that gives me, but I am a sql sysadmin. ¿Any ideas?

Thanks!!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is the SSIS Instance being ran by an admin account? This might be the source of your issue.

**Change Log On Account:**

Open Services (services.msc) > SQL Server Integration Services XX.0 > Properties > Log On

Comment: Hi, is configured with "local system" same as all other sql services. I attach image in the question

Comment: Could you check your NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM if it has sysadmin role?

Comment: Hello, the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM dont have the permissions.
I gave it to him, but it still fails